# Messagebox not blocking events on a windows.forms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have this code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
    }
```

the timer is enabled, with interval = 100.

This result in an infinite number of message boxes to appear over each other, when I was expecting them to simply BLOCK the next event until the current messagebox is closed.

In more complicated applications this could lead to unpreditable results, and its as if more than 1 thread have access to the same function, but actually it is the same thread.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message box is a modal dialog which pumps the message queue. And so that allows for the timer tick messages to fire, since they are posted to the GUI thread's message queue.

This is always the case for a modal dialog that is shown in the GUI thread. Since each thread has only one message queue, the modal dialog's message pump will pull of the timer tick messages.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening exactly how it should. The tick event is powered by the message loop (unless you're using a threaded variant) and will be called repeatedly unless you block the message loop in some way (think `Thread.Sleep` or non message based code execution).

The message box doesn't block, it's just another window and as long as the message pump of the application is functioning so will the window, and so as each tick happens new dialogs can be created and stacked up.

A quick solution to this is something like:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
    timer1.Start();
}
```

This would stop the timer, show a dialog and allow the timer to recover after the dialog is closed. This means you'd only get the one dialog and not a perpetual stack of them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Depends on the timer used. A threaded timer will fire off code repeatedly iirc, just queues up a threadpool item, I'm not sure on the Windows timer you might be right there, but I thought it was just a message in itself, so surely the loop would pick it up and fire again?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think so. The tick will happen but the callback for the event can happen multiple times. If the callback doesn't block execution of any kind then the ticks should just keep happening.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No not exactly the same time. My point is if they don't block, which is how you can have multiple forms open at the same time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And thats the point in case, multiple dialogs can be shown because the tick event does not stop the next tick event from happening (unless you did something like Thread.Sleep or blocked the message pump in some way).

Comment: MessageBox.Show has it's own message loop, which WILL receive the message and again execute the same timer.

Comment: OK, well I'll clean up this mess of comments now. And I approve of your edit. +1